# Why @Html.LabelFor can get resource string but @Model cannot in ASP.NET MVC4(razor engine)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, resources

I am working with a ASP.NET MVC4 application. I have created a view model which contains menu items and I can switch languages in page by Resources file.

```
#region Properties
[Display(Name = "MenuText", ResourceType = typeof(App.App_Resources.Menu))]
public string menuText { get; set; }

public List<MenuItem> menuItems { get; set; }
#endregion
```

However, I want to get this resource string in my .cshtml file, then I try as following

```
@model App.Models.MenuViewModel
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.menuText)            <- Success
@Html.DisplayForModel("menuText")                  <- Success
@Model.menuText                                    <- Fail
```

I inserted a break point and found out that **Model** contains a property which name is **menuText** but value is **null**. And I checked that **Html** also contains a property **Model** and its **menuText** also is **null**.
However, **menuItems** has items since I assign objects in constructor.

1. Why the **menuText** cannot be initialized and assigned value to it?
2. Why I can succeed to show the resource string with first two but **Model.menuText** is null and fail to show anything? What is different between the models in **@Html.XXX** and **@Model**?

Comment: It will be much better if you only ask one question at a time. #1 & #2 are related so those are probably okay, but it might be better if you just create a new question for #3.

Comment: Thanks for you comment~ I think #1 and #2 may be the main problem that I need to solve~ ^^ I will create a new question for #3 later if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Model.menuText` retrieves the raw string value stored within the `menuText` property. Attributes are ignored.

Using `LabelFor` causes the `Display` attribute of the property to be examined. The localised string is stored in the attribute, not the property.

Note that I think the Model object/class should not be used to store information for display (that's what `ViewData` is for), but rather only for round-trip data that is sent from the client to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just want to find any ways to store the information for display in one space and then no need to modify any code in both .cs or .cshtml files. Has any alternative ways?